# Containing bar value numbers inside the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to create a bar plot with values for each bar, but the values exceed the plot's width.

[image: bar chart]

Here's the code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
width = 0.75
ind = np.arange(len(values))
ax.barh(ind, values, width, color = colors)
ax.set_yticks(ind)
ax.set_yticklabels(names)
plt.title('\'%s\' attribute distribution' % name)
plt.xlabel('Count')
plt.ylabel(name)

for i, v in enumerate(values):
  ax.text(v,i, ' '+str(v), va='center', fontweight='bold')

for i, r in enumerate(ratios):
  ax.text(r,i, ' '+str(r)+'%', color = 'white', fontweight='bold')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Try `plt.xlim(None, 1.2*values.max())`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest `plt.xlim(None, 1.2*values.max())` throws an error, but I get the ide of what you proposed. `plt.xlim(None, 1.2*max(values))` - this seems to work just fine, thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plt.xlim(None, 1.2*max(values))` seems to do the trick.

[image: bar chart]

Thanks to [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this "box" around the graph. try adding this to your code.

```py
for spine in plt.gca().spines.values():
    spine.set_visible(False)

plt.tick_params(top='off', bottom='off', left='off', right='off', labelleft='off', labelbottom='on')
```

Comment: While this does solve my issue it makes the graph look weird.

Answer (score 0):

See if adding this helps now

```py
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(right=1.7)
```

Comment: This does help but it elongates the graph by a lot. It could work for the values that I have on this plot but it may not work for values going over 10,000 so I don't think it's a good solution

Comment: Yeah, that's true. In your case the graph has become too long, I hope I can help someone else who sees your question tho.